# Roslyn VSIX analyzer does not work with VS2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, roslyn, vsix

Short story - my Roslyn .vsix analyzer does not do anything in VS 2013.

I have a VS extension (.vsix) built with Roslyn, quite close to the ones described here [tutorial for analyzers](https://joshvarty.wordpress.com/2015/04/30/learn-roslyn-now-part-10-introduction-to-analyzers/) and [tutorial for fixes](https://joshvarty.wordpress.com/2015/08/03/learn-roslyn-now-part-11-introduction-to-code-fixes/) .

I used VS 2015 Community to develop the extension. It  works ok in debug instance of VS 2015 and, when I install the resulting .vsix, in normal VS 2015.

I have configured the manifest to also allow installation into VS 2012 and 2013 and installed it into VS 2013 Community on the same machine, however, it doesn't work. It shows up in the list of installed extensions (and the studio was launched after it was installed), but does not show diagnostics and code fix suggestions.

Am I doing something wrong, or are Roslyn .vsix extensions only for VS 2015 and later?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Roslyn was only introduced to VS in VS2015, so no, Roslyn based VSIXes will not work in VS2013.